# AWS Glue Dynamic Filtering - Filter one dynamic frame using another dynamic frame

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, filtering, aws-glue

I am trying to filter dynamic filtering based on the data residing in another dynamic frame , i am working on [join and relational example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/join_and_relationalize.md) , in this code person and membership dynamic frames are joined by id but i would like to filter persons  based on id present in membership DF , below is code where i put static values

```
    import sys
from awsglue.transforms import Join
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# catalog: database and table names
db_name = "legislators"
tbl_persons = "persons_json"
tbl_membership = "memberships_json"
tbl_organization = "organizations_json"



# Create dynamic frames from the source tables 
persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=db_name, table_name=tbl_persons)
memberships = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=db_name, table_name=tbl_membership)
orgs = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=db_name, table_name=tbl_organization)

persons = persons.drop_fields(['links', 'identifiers','other_names', 'images','contact_details'])


# Keep the fields we need and rename some.
orgs = orgs.drop_fields(['other_names', 'identifiers','links'])


fileredPersons = Filter.apply(frame = persons,
                              f = lambda x: x["id"] in ["0005af3a-9471-4d1f-9299-737fff4b9b46", "00aca284-9323-4953-bb7a-1bf6f5eefe95"])
print "Filtered record count:  ", fileredPersons.count()
```

below is the filter logic

```
 fileredPersons = Filter.apply(frame = persons,
                                  f = lambda x: x["id"] in ["0005af3a-9471-4d1f-9299-737fff4b9b46", "00aca284-9323-4953-bb7a-1bf6f5eefe95"])
```

I would like pass person_id column present in membership DF into filter function condition, basically filters persons having in in memberships , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use pyspark instead of glue than this can be done using glue I'm not sure

Comment: can you please details  provide how to do it  using pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply perform the inner join instead of filtering like

```
persons_filtered = persons.alias('persons').join(memberships, persons.id==memberships.id).select('persons.*')
```

This will give you the filtered values only.
If your memberships df is small or kind of lookup then you can even broadcast it for faster results

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
persons_filtered = persons.alias('persons').join(broadcast(memberships), persons.id==memberships.id).select('persons.*')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i get invalid syntax for "persons_filtered = persons.join(memberships, persons.id==memberships.id).select(persons.*)" is there any issue with this

Comment: i converted Glue Dyanmic Frame to Dataframe and applied code given by you